# Can I ask for titles of background music in some particular movie?

Tags: discussion

I don't know if this is allowed. I want to ask background music because I don't know their title or the original version since it is played instrumentally.

Comment: As long as it's a sci-fi (or fantasy) film then sure, ask away

Comment: Of course, [Shazam](https://www.shazam.com/gb/apps) might be able to help too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Yes**, I'm pretty sure this would come under (from the [help centre](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)):

> Behind-the-scenes and fandom information

Assuming the movie in question is science fiction or fantasy, but that goes without saying.

Examples of previous questions similar to what you seem to be asking about:

- [What is the song played in the "End of Line" club on Tron Legacy?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/46302/31394)
- [What is the name of the "polka style" music preceding the Waltz in Final Fantasy VIII?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/91489/31394)
- [In TOS, what's the origin and name of the clarinet comedy sound effect found in "A Private Little War" and other episodes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/152226/31394)
- [What is the Hound singing?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/168709/31394)

We even have whole tags for [music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) (99 questions) and [theme-music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-music) (5 questions), although they don't seem to have very clear usage patterns ... *note to self: make new meta post about these tags*.

Comment: should i use both of the tags?

Comment: @BookStriker You can, but it doesn't really matter since the two tags [will probably be merged soon anyway](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11488/31394).