# The music of the tags

Tags: discussion, tags

The tag [music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) (99 questions) has the following tag wiki excerpt (and no tag wiki):

> Refers to musical themes, cues, or scores present in works of science fiction. Usually used in relation to film or tv series.

In practice, the tag seems to have been used for at least three different types of questions.

1. Questions about music which appears in a work of sci-fi or fantasy, e.g. [Which version of the Imperial March plays just after Vader gets his new suit?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/144173/31394) and [What are the lyrics and translation for the Nazgûl theme music?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/109806/31394)
2. Questions about music which *refers to* a work of sci-fi or fantasy, e.g. [What is the first mention of Star Wars in a hit song?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/150736/31394) and [Which Star Trek: TNG episodes are sampled in the song "Data & Picard" from artist Pogo?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/151289/31394)
3. Story-ID questions about stories with a musical theme, e.g. [Short stories with musical themes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/156291/31394) and [What is short story of man stranded on planet with a musical alien](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/116532/31394)

We also have a second tag [theme-music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-music), with 5 questions all of which fall into the first of the three categories listed above.

### **How should these tags actually be used?**

- Are we OK with [music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) being used for three different types of question? If not, should we split it into two or three different tags and/or retag some questions? Should we rewrite the tag wiki?
- Does [theme-music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-music) deserve to be a separate tag, or should it be merged into [music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music)?

Comment: What about the other tags such as `rock-music`, `musical` (probably relevant to story-id), and `music-video`?

Comment: @Skooba Oh good lord, how deep does this pit go?

Answer (score 5):

**Merge them.**

Music is broad term, but reasonably well understood in the context of our site. Experts in the production and usage of music within the works of science fiction and fantasy will likely have a range of applicable knowledge.

The last [theme-music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/theme-music) question was asked roughly two years at the time of this posting. While an inactive tag shouldn't just go away, it gives us a good indication that the broader [music](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/music) is likely to garner better results for searching, asking, and answering questions.

As for the different usages we have seen... all that takes is a well written tag-wiki!

Comment: I like the idea of musical being better, although I strongly approve of this non-deletion belief

Comment: OK, if this meta post remains upvoted I'll merge the two tags. What about the different usages of [tag:music]?

Comment: `all that takes is a well written tag-wiki` - but first we have to define a definition for which use is appropriate before writing the wiki...